# ng serve/angular - Allow 404s for assets not found - eg if an image doesn't exist return 404 don't redirect

Tags: angular, angular6

Maybe I'm thinking about this all wrong but!

I have a scenario where if I refer to
/assets/my-icons/some-image-that-doesnt-exist.jpg

Instead of returning a 404, Angular tries to redirect the user to the '' route in my route config which returns a 200.

I have the folder defined in angular.json:

```
"assets": [
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ]
```

Is there a way in config to force it to return the 404 for the image not being found?

It is driving me a bit mad :)

UPDATE: It looks to be similar to this but seeing as my CLI version is 6.1.5 it would seem it should be after that fix -  https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2989

Comment: Is that just for `ng serve` or `ng build` as well?

Comment: any special reason to add - src/assets - my-icons and events folder specifically ?  (why not include src/assets only one and then refer assets . and for image error genrally (error) method is used to handle that in img tag, angular will go for routing only in case i guess you open that assets as a url in browser

Comment: Hi David it is ng serve. Yes sorry I removed the sub-folders from assets they weren't required in the config file. It sounds something like this issue is happening: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2989

But I'm using CLI version 6.1.5 which you think would have their fix in it

I'm now wondering if I need to run a custom webpack config to mimic their changes. I wouldn't have thought that static assets would be routed rather than 404'd